# Flow3 - How to create a simple-to-use many-to-many relation?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, typo3, entity-relationship, typo3-flow

I am currently working on my first many-to-many relation in Flow3 (Doctrine) between "Project" and "Person" and want to add, get and remove elements from both controllers.

Project declaration:

```
class Project {
 // ...

 /**
  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection</*...*/\Person>
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="/*...*/\Person", mappedBy="projects")
  */
  protected $persons;

 // ... 
}
```

Person declaration:

```
class Person {
 // ...

 /**
  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection</*...*/\Project>
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="/*...*/\Project", inversedBy="persons")
  */
  protected $projects;

 // ...
}
```

But I only can add/remove Objects on the "Person" (inversed) side. At least I can get the Objects from both sides. Do I realy have to build a workaround on the "Project" side with an "Person" object or is there a simple solution I missed?

Here is the code snippet of the projectController, that doesn't work:

```
public function addpersonAction() {
    $param = $this->request->getArgument('project');
    $project = $this->projectRepository->findByIdentifier($param['__identity']);
    $selectedPersons = $this->request->getArgument('selPersons');
    foreach($selectedPersons as $person)
    {
        if( strlen($person['__identity']) > 0 )
        {
            $project->addPerson($this->personRepository->findByIdentifier($person['__identity']));
        }
    }
    $this->projectRepository->update($project);

    //...
}
```

And the addPerson() function in Project:

```
public function addPerson(\DS\Datenbank\Domain\Model\Person $person) {
    if( !$this->persons->contains($person) )
      $this->persons->add($person);
  }
```

Comment: Is this action invoked by a GET request or by a POST request? Data will only be persisted automatically in POST/SAVE/DELETE requests, but not in a GET request. You will have to persist data manually in your action invoked by a GET request.

Comment: the whole code is a bit awkward and contains lots of unnecessary stuff which makes it more complicated; however, does your problem still exist?

Answer (score 0):

For me this works. I assume you have the appropriate add-methods in both models. Btw: you do not need "targetEntity" in flow, it is found automagically by the @var declaration above.

Is your database up to date? Did you flush the cache?

Comment: Thanks for the targetEntity information but it still doesn't work with the add / remove functions on the mappedBy Object. (e.g. "Project")

Comment: Can you get the related objects from either side? Oder doesn't this work either?

Comment: Yip, the get function works. The add/remove function btw delivers no error messages but they don't do anything on the database. I added you my code snippet of the projectController where it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I checked the "work around" alternative and it works.
So to summarize what I did:

=> Instead of add/remove the **Person** on the **Project** side I add/remove the **Project** on the **Person** side but in the same old **addpersonAction()** from **Project** you see above.

But the question is still open: Does it realy only work this way ans why?

Comment: Please, look at my comment under your question. Wich request type do you use?

Comment: yep, the add function came via GET call.

Comment: The repositories are not automatically persisted in a GET call. You need to persist them manually.